# How do I set the theme on a KCCalendar control?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying out the Flex 3.2 version of the KCCalendar control.  On the live demo here:

http://www.flex-component.com/demo/kccalendar/

it shows three different themes, one of which, is an Outlook theme.  I was just wondering how exactly I set this theme either in the mxml or in the action script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
ThemeSwitcher.applyOutlookTheme(calendarComponent); //calendarComponent is the id of the calendar component.
```

to change the theme.  I discovered this by reading the source code of the demo page you posted.  You can right click on the demo page, and choose View Source.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks.  I keep forgetting you can View Source on flex/flash.